# Scrapy - TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to iterate through a list of URL's return from the callback passed to scrapy request, but I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Request' object is not iterable
```

The following works. I can see all the extracted URL's flood the terminal:

```
import scrapy

class PLSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pl'
    start_urls = [ 'https://example.com' ]

    def genres(self, resp):
        for genre in resp.css('div.sub-menus a'):
            yield {
                'genre': genre.css('::text').extract_first(),
                'url': genre.css('::attr(href)').extract_first() 
            }

    def extractSamplePackURLs(self, resp):
        return {
            'packs': resp.css('h4.product-title a::attr(href)').extract()
        }

    def extractPackData(self, resp):
        return {
            'title': resp.css('h1.product-title::text'),
            'description': resp.css('div.single-product-description p').extract_first()
        }

    def parse(self, resp):
        for genre in self.genres(resp):
            samplePacks = scrapy.Request(genre['url'], callback=self.extractSamplePackURLs)
            yield samplePacks
```

But if I replace the `yield samplePacks` line with:

```
    def parse(self, resp):
        for genre in self.genres(resp):
            samplePacks = scrapy.Request(genre['url'], callback=self.extractSamplePackURLs)
            for pack in samplePacks:
                yield pack
```

... I get the error I posted above.

Why is this and how can I loop through the returned value of the callback?

Comment: You yield the sample pack data in your callback function... All that yielding a `Request` object does is add another page to scrape with associated callback - it's call back should then yield (not return) the data...

Comment: samplePacks doesn't have an __iter__() defined so it cannot be iterated on?

Comment: I think I may be getting confused here. I thought `Request` would return the list from the callback?

Comment: @JonClements If I replace the return with `yield` I still get the same error.

Comment: @BugHunterUK the yielding of the request just adds the page to crawl... You  put the looping in the `extractSamplePackURLs` callback and loop over `resp.css('h4...')` to get the data... The `Request` tells the spider where to go next, and once it's retrieved, the callback is executed, which is where you then do what you want with the content of the page (in this case loop over your sample data)

Comment: @JonClements Oh I see what you mean. Things could get hairy because I need to make another request within that callback. I wanted to try keep it clean. Thanks for your time and explanations. Edit: Ignore me, that was actually much simpler.

Comment: @BugHunterUK just remember to yield everything. And it's fine if on one call back you yield the data items to the pipeline and also yield more requests from it with another call back... (eg you visit a page and extract a list of items, then yield requests links found on that page that require a different call back to extract things)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yielding `Request` objects in `scrapy.Spider` callbacks only tells Scrapy framework to enqueue HTTP requests. It yields HTTP requests objects, just that. It does not download them immediately. Or give back control until they are downloaded, ie. after the yield, you still don't have the result. `Request` objects are not promises, futures, deferred. Scrapy is not designed the same as various async frameworks.

These `Request` objects will *eventually* get processed by the framework's downloader, and the response body from each HTTP request will be passed to the associated callback.
This is the basis of Scrapy's asynchronous programming pattern.

If you want to do something more "procedural-like" in which `yield request(...)` gets you the HTTP response the next time you have control, you can have a look at https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-inline-requests/.